# How does one say that someone pours some drink on another guy?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, sentence-request

Image two people A and B are talking in a bar or somewhere else. A says something that hurts B. B gets angry and suddenly holds forward his\her wine glass so that the drink in the glass splashes on A's face or clothes.

Can I say B splashes the drink on A's face? Is there alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Splash" is OK, but "throw" is better. "Splash" sounds like it's kind of a light, momentary action, done somewhat in fun, but "throw" is clearly intentional and violent.

"Throw" could also be misunderstood as throwing the vessel as well as the liquid. But I would say it's a common enough expression that the reader is likely to picture it [correctly](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/pfbmN8KNy94).

Also, "in" rather than "on":

> He threw his drink in my face!

Often we use "in" for faces. I'll have to think about why that is...

Comment: Do I have to use 'splash' with '**in** his face' too?

Comment: @Michael Either one seems OK to me for "splash". For "splashed water on his face", I picture someone trying to rouse an unconscious person for some reason.